# Upgrade ClickOnce Application using Windows Installer. Is this possible?

Tags: deployment, installation, windows-installer, clickonce

Few machines have 'MyApp.exe' installed using ClickOnce. And I have created a new MSI Windows Installer for 'MyApp.exe' using MS Visual Studio 2013 Setup and Deployment. I have a requirement that when my new MSI Installer runs it has to automatically remove/uninstall all previous 'MyApp.exe' (installed using ClickOnce) and install the new exe. Installer has to do it as part of its installation process.

Is this even possible? ClickOnce doesn't make any registry entries, so how can I get the Upgrade codes/Product codes which I can feed to Windows Installed 'Upgrade Paths' to upgrade it. ClickOnce is per user installation, but Windows Installer is not.

Is it even possible for Windows Installer to uninstall ClickOnce installed application ?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickOnce is a per-user deployment experience and MSI is usually a per-machine experience.   Per machine can't clean up other people's profiles.   The only way I know is to do an active setup trick to run a program for each user who logs on and then execute a script to do cleanup.  Either that or put first-run code in the applicaton itself to do the same.